# Need Help Using CHARINDEX to Create a New Variable

Tags: sql, string, charindex

I'm trying to take the second number in the variable description and make a new variable. However, I'm not too familiar with string manipulation. Below is a small example of the variable description, I'm having a hard time formatting it because the first number changes in size.

```
Description 
4 Matching notifications 11 Updates
32 Matching notifications 12 Updates
1211 Matching notifications 1 Updates
```

Below this is a rough idea of the code I thought would originally work.

```
 SELECT 
     LEFT(Description, CHARNDEX('Updates', Description)-1) AS Second_variable
 FROM X
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the RDBMS you are using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql etc.)

Comment: Unrelated, but: that "second_variable" is not a "variable", but a column

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky in SQL Server.  One method is:

```
select s.value as second_variable
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) s.value
      from string_split(description, ' ') s
      where description like concat('% ', s.value, ' Updates')
     ) s;
```

This extracts the individual "words" from the string and then chooses the one that matches the value before the last `' Updates'`.

Comment: Thank you for the useful response! I appreciate it.